# Conditional inline_policy in aws_iam_role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

Im new at Terraform and im trying to create ecsTaskExcecutionRoles for each service i have, i create a module that allows to send a list of secrets, i want to make the inline policy that allows the access optional.

i tried putting inside the inline_policy something like:

```
count = length(var.secrets_arn_list) > 0 ? 1 : 0
```

but it's not possible use count in that place

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_tasks_execution_role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_tasks_execution_role" {
  name        = "TaskExecutionRole-${var.environment}-${var.project}"

  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_tasks_execution_role.json}"

  inline_policy {
    name = "SecretsManagerAccess-${var.project}-${var.environment}"
    policy = jsonencode({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
              "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
              "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
              "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
            ],
            "Resource": var.secrets_arn_list 
          }
        ]
    })
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_tasks_execution_role" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_tasks_execution_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

Someone knows how to solve it?

Comment: So the inline policy should be there under what condition, `secrets_arn_list` being greater than 0?

Comment: if the list of secrets arns is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way using `dynamic` [1] and `for_each` meta-argument [2]:

```
dynamic "inline_policy" {
  for_each = length(var.secrets_arn_list) > 0 ? [1] : []
  content {
    name = "SecretsManagerAccess-${var.project}-${var.environment}"
    policy = jsonencode({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy",
              "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
              "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
              "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
            ],
            "Resource": var.secrets_arn_list 
          }
        ]
    })
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 1):

Either use a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks), instead of `count`, or move the policy into a separate Terraform [aws_iam_role_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy) resource and put the `count` on that resource.